# Dapper query, combining attributes to use with pagination

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, dapper

I have that query that shows all my Boats, but I would just like to show the active boats.

```
    public Pagination<Boats> GetAll(string name , int pageSize, int pageNumber)
    {
        var cn = Db.Database.Connection;

        var sql = @"SELECT * FROM Boats" +
                  "WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR Name LIKE @Name + '%')" +
                  "ORDER BY [Name ] " +
                  "OFFSET " + pageSize * (pageNumber - 1) + " ROWS " +
                  "FETCH NEXT " + pageSize + " ROWS ONLY " +
                  " " +
                  "SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Boats" +
                  "WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR Name LIKE @Name + '%')";

        var multi = cn.QueryMultiple(sql, new { Name = name });
        var boats= multi.Read<Boats >();
        var total = multi.Read<int>().FirstOrDefault();

        var paginationList= new Pagination<Boats>()
        {
            List = boats,
            Count = total
        };

        return paginationList;

    }
```

I have the active and excluded attributes in the table, so I tried to show only the boats that were active, but with this query, it keeps returning all records from the boat table, like frist one

```
                  var sql = @"SELECT * FROM Boats " +
                  "WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR Name LIKE @Name + '%' AND  Active=1 AND Excluded=0)" +
                  "ORDER BY [Name] " +
                  "OFFSET " + pageSize * (pageNumber - 1) + " ROWS " +
                  "FETCH NEXT " + pageSize + " ROWS ONLY " +
                  " " +
                  "SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Boats " +
                  "WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR Name LIKE @Name + '%' AND  Active=1 AND Excluded=0)";
```

Any Ideas how can I combine the Name attribute with the Active and Excluded attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Remove it from the parenthesis:

`"WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR Name LIKE @Name + '%') AND  Active=1 AND Excluded=0"`